# Give control of your pc to others via Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to give control to a participant in a meeting but I cannot see "Give control" from MS Teams.

The description below suggests otherwise:

> Give control
>
> On the sharing toolbar, select Give control.
>
> Select the name of the person you want to give control to.
>
> Teams sends a notification to that person to let them know you’re
> sharing control. While you’re sharing control, they can make
> selections, edits, and other modifications to the shared screen.
>
> To take control back, select Take back control.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-content-in-a-meeting-in-teams-fcc2bf59-aecd-4481-8f99-ce55dd836ce8

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the other suggestions, here's another. According to the docs, Give Control is disabled if you don't have hardware acceleration enabled.

> This issue occurs because the device that you are using doesn't have a graphics processing unit (GPU) installed, or GPU hardware acceleration is disabled. The Give Control drop-down menu doesn't work unless hardware acceleration is supported on the system. This behavior is by design.

You can check to see if your system supports hardware acceleration by following these instructions

> To prevent this behavior, make sure that your system supports hardware acceleration. To verify the same, you can browse edge://gpu/ in Microsoft Edge or chrome://gpu/ in Google Chrome. If you can see any value in it stating "Software only" or "hardware acceleration unavailable", that means the system does not support it. For more help, we recommend that you contact your hardware provider.

Taken from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-conferencing/give-control-doesn%E2%80%99t-work-sharescreen

Answer (score 0):

MS Teams work on a basis of requests for any permissions.
The user that needs control will have to click on request control 1st.
Once they have done that, you will get a prompt to approve the request by giving control to that user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your admin might disable the setting to give / request control. Go to https://admin.teams.microsoft.com and proceed to Meetings > Meeting policies > [any-policy] > Content sharing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your info. I wish I could give more than one answer.